# Error when running Pax-Exam tests in windows

Tags: osgi, pax-exam

I am getting the following error when running Pax-Exam tests in windows. And found this issue https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXEXAM-701

Pax-version 4.7.0 and OSGi version org.eclipse.osgi-3.10.2.v20150203-1939

How can we overcome this issue?.

```html
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error while renaming bundle file to final location: C:\Users\aruna\AppData\Local\Temp\1450091333855-0\org.eclipse.osgi\5\0\bundleFile
 at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getContentFile0(Storage.java:767)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getContentFile(Storage.java:743)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.install(Storage.java:508)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:146)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:139)
 at org.ops4j.pax.exam.nat.internal.NativeTestContainer.installAndStartBundles(NativeTestContainer.java:308)
 at org.ops4j.pax.exam.nat.internal.NativeTestContainer.start(NativeTestContainer.java:177)
 at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.EagerSingleStagedReactor.setUp(EagerSingleStagedReactor.java:86)
 at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.EagerSingleStagedReactor.beforeClass(EagerSingleStagedReactor.java:136)
 at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.ReactorManager.beforeClass(ReactorManager.java:448)
 at org.ops4j.pax.exam.testng.listener.PaxExam.runByDriver(PaxExam.java:443)
 at org.ops4j.pax.exam.testng.listener.PaxExam.run(PaxExam.java:308)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:212)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:652)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:845)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1153)
 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1199)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1124)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1032)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:295)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:90)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is the following:

- set up in your IDE a conditional breakpoint on `BundleException` constructor. Condition is that the message argument contains *"Error while renaming"*
- the test should be set up to run in debug mode with waiting for debugger attach
- the test should be set up to start with with [file leak detector](http://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org/) agent
- start the test
- attach the debugger
- as soon as the breakpoint stops look for
  the file name which you see in the message in the leak detector web page. There you will see the
  stack of the thread which has created the file handler and you will
  find your bug.

The PAX option you need will be something like this:

```
vmOptions("-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005", "-javaagent:path/to/file-leak-detector.jar=http=19999")
```

If it is a PAX bug, please report it to their team.